# VueRouter + VueJs2 + MetisMenu = Collapse error

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new VueJs student, and i want to make a Menu and a Second level menu into this.
I'm want to use Jquery-MetisMenu, so a downloaded it, put it on my Index.html and i made a router view to the Menu.

**Here is my Menu.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="app">
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label"> Here First Level </span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>

                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                        <li><a href="#"> Here Second Level </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</template>
```

**Routes.js**

```
import ContentTest from './ContentTest.vue'
import Menu from './Menu.vue'

const routes = [
  //{path: '/login', component: LoginView }, 
    { 
        path: '/Menu',
        component: Menu,
        children: [
        {
            path: '/Menu/ContentTest',
            component: ContentTest,
            name: 'ContentTest 1'
        }]
    }]

export default routes
```

**Body of Index.Html**

```
  <body>

    <!-- Main View -->
    <div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Script Files -->
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

The problem is with the collapse, when i click on "Here First Level", the URL changes to "#" and it get lost. I tried to put nothing inside href, but didn't work.

Waiting answers! Thanks a lot!!

> @EDIT

Solved! I add on footer of Index.html

```
$(function() {
  $('#side-menu').metisMenu({
    toggle: false
  });
});
```

and it worked!

=)

Answer (score 2):

@Johnson worked for me to

```
$(function() {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu({
        toggle: false
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah, i already solved this question. the solution is on the question too ;)